# Добавление столбца в DataFrame по части мультииндекса

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Есть две таблицы с данными и мультииндесом:

```
ind = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], names=['a', 'b'])
data1 = pd.DataFrame({'data1': range(1, 10)}, index=ind)
data2 = pd.DataFrame({'data2': [10, 11, 12]}, index=pd.Index(range(1, 4), name='a'))
print(data1)
print(data2)
```

Out:

```
        data1
a   b   
1   1   1
    2   2
    3   3
2   1   4
    2   5
    3   6
3   1   7
    2   8
    3   9

    data2
a   
1   10
2   11
3   12
```

Необходимо в первом датафрейме создать новый столбец в который поместить данные столбца data2 из второго датафрейма по совмещению индексов 'а'. Т.е. должно получиться следующее:

```
        data1  data2
a   b   
1   1    1      10
    2    2      10
    3    3      10
2   1    4      20
    2    5      20
    3    6      20
3   1    7      30
    2    8      30
    3    9      30
```

Можно, конечно воспользоваться различными функциями объединения типа merge, concat, но что-то подсказывает, что должен быть более простой и красивый вариант. Типа:

```
data1['data2'] = data2['data2']
```

Вероятно с какими-либо вариациями.

Спасибо!

Comment: Пришел в голову только такой вариант: data1['data2'] = data2.reindex(data1.index, level='a')    Но для случая составного индекса второй таблицы (data2) такой прием уже не проходит.

Comment: было бы неплохо привести также пример `data2` с составным индексом, если вы такой ожидаете...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один из вариантов:

```
In [80]: data1 = data1.join(data2, on='a', how='left')

In [81]: data1
Out[81]:
     data1  data2
a b
1 1      1     10
  2      2     10
  3      3     10
2 1      4     11
  2      5     11
  3      6     11
3 1      7     12
  2      8     12
  3      9     12
```